# How to properly handle Object/Buffer/Uint8Array in AsyncWorker?

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp, node.js-addon, node-addon-api

I couldn't find in the documentation and examples how to properly handle `Object/Buffer/Uint8Array` parameters in `AsyncWorker`?

The task: I'd like to receive data as `Uint8Array` and use it in `AsyncWorker`.

If I understand correctly, the data can be garbage collected.

Should I:

- Wrap object in `ObjectReference` and pass it to `AsyncWorker` constructor?
- Wrap `Uint8Array` in ObjectReference`?
- Wrap `uint8_t* data` as something?

Naive code:

```cpp
#include "napi.h"

class DoHeavyMathWorker : public Napi::AsyncWorker {
  public:
    DoHeavyMathWorker(const Napi::Env& env, uint8_t* data)
      : Napi::AsyncWorker{env, "DoHeavyMathWorker"},
      m_deferred{env},
      m_data{data}
      {}

    Napi::Promise GetPromise() { return m_deferred.Promise(); }

  protected:
    void Execute() {
      // heavy math with data
      if (m_data[0] == 0) {
        m_result = 1;
      } else {
        m_result = 2;
      }
    }

    void OnOK() { m_deferred.Resolve(Napi::Number::New(Env(), m_result)); }
    void OnError(const Napi::Error& err) { m_deferred.Reject(err.Value()); }

  private:
    Napi::Promise::Deferred m_deferred;
    uint8_t* m_data;
    uint32_t m_result;
};

Napi::Value DoHeavyMath(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info) {
  Napi::Env env = info.Env();

  if (!info[0].IsObject()) {
    Napi::TypeError::New(env, "arg must be an object")
        .ThrowAsJavaScriptException();
    return env.Undefined();
  }
  Napi::Object obj = info[0].As<Napi::Object>();
  uint8_t* data = obj.Get("data").As<Napi::Uint8Array>().Data();

  DoHeavyMathWorker* worker = new DoHeavyMathWorker(env, data);
  worker->Queue();
  return worker->GetPromise();
}

Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
  exports.Set("doHeavyMath", Napi::Function::New(env, DoHeavyMath));
  return exports;
}

NODE_API_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Init)
```

JS part:

```js
const result = await addon.doHeavyMath({
  data: new Uint8Array([42]),
});
console.log('result:', result);
```

---

- Related but not answered question: https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/issues/1221
- Code is based on example https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples/blob/main/src/5-async-work/async_work_promise/node-addon-api/worker.h
- `AsyncWorker` docs https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/blob/main/doc/async_worker.md

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a persistent reference and keep it around for as long as you need the data. Note, that persistent references can only be created and destroyed on the main thread.

You should create it on the heap in the function that creates the `AsyncWorker`:

```cpp
auto *persistent = new Napi::ObjectReference(
  Napi::Persistent(array_buffer.As<Napi::Object>()));
```

Pass this reference to the `AsyncWorker` and delete it in the `AsyncWorker` callbacks - `OnOK` and `OnError`:

```cpp
// This is everything needed to free the underlying reference
delete persistent;
```

Comment: Why is it not enough to just create `ObjectReference`?

`auto *ref = new Napi::ObjectReference(array_buffer.As<Napi::Object>());`

Comment: This will create a heap-allocated reference, but it won't be persistent. This reference can be used outside of the function that created it, but does not protect from the GC. It is a *weak* reference.